# xml schema check fail with pattern match

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

i have such boilerplate code in xsd schema.

```
      <xs:attribute name="version" use="required">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="1.1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.3"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.4"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.5"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.6"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.7"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.8"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.9"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.10"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.11"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1.12"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
```

that I simply want to replace with pattern as follows.

```
<xs:pattern value="1.[1-9]|[1-1][0-2]"/>
```

it passes the 1.2 or 1.6 but fails with "1.10". with lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid: Element 'sfd', attribute 'version': [facet 'pattern'] The value '1.10' is not accepted by the pattern '1.[1-9]|[1-1][0-2]'

I thought [1-9]|[1-1][0-2] represents the range between 1-9 and 10-12.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex (see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/0EFYpg/4)) matches a string that either

- `1.[1-9]` - starts with `1`, then has any char other than a line break char and the a digit from `1` to `9`
- `|` - or
- `[1-1][0-2]` - starts with `1` (note `[1-1]` = `1`) and then a digit from `0` to `2`.

You may use

```
<xs:pattern value="1\.(1[0-2]|[1-9])"/>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0EFYpg/2). Bearing in mind that XSD schema regex pattern must match the entire string, here is what it matches:

- `1` - matches `1`
- `\.` - matches a literal dot (`.` without an escape symbol matches any char but a line break char)
- `(1[0-2]|[1-9])` - a capturing group (note XSD Schema regex does not support non-capturing ones) matching `10`, `11`, `12` or a digit from `1` to `9` range.

Comment: you are too fast... I edited the question a bit. it is not just to 10, it is counting... e.g. it is 12 now, and future maybe to 20. what i failed to get is why the [1-9]|[1-1][0-0] does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try parentheses:

```
<xs:pattern value="1\.([1-9]|1[0-2])"/>
```

Note the escaped ".", otherwise you will match things like 1$12. And I think `[1-1]` is probably allowed, but `1` seems simpler.